# Datatable - Newly added row to DOM breaks mobile browser

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatable to display set of rows which has some expand button (details-control class with icon "fas fa-angle-right") like below,

[image]

this expands to like below in desktop view however breaks in mobile view for some unknown reason to me.

[image]

This works fine in Chrome viewport for Desktop, however, if I reduce the scale of the viewport it stops working (i don't see any error too in the console.log)

see below for the viewport not working in mobile view

[image]

My coding to add the new row data via AJAX is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var datatable = $("#datatable_list").DataTable({
                    serverSide: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/users/",
                        method: "POST"
                    },
                    pageLength: 50,
                    lengthChange: false,
                    order: [[1, "desc"]],
                    dom: '<"pull-left"if><"top pull-right"p>rt<"bottom pull-right"p><"clear">',    
                    createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
                        //Add common class
                        $(row).addClass("mode");   
                        $(row).attr("id","user_"+data.user_id);
                        // Set the data-status attribute, and add a class

                            if(data.mode == "active"){    
                                $(row).addClass("table-success");    
                            }else if(data.mode == "pending"){
                                $(row).addClass("table-warning");    
                            }
                            else if(data.mode == "deleted"){
                                $(row).addClass("table-danger");    
                            }else if(data.mode == "hellban"){
                                $(row).addClass("mode-hellban");    
                            }
                            else if( data.mode == "suspended"){
                                $(row).addClass("mode-suspended");    
                            }else if( data.mode== "disapproved" ){
                                $(row).addClass("mode-disapproved");    
                            }else if( data.mode== "hidden" ){
                                $(row).addClass("mode-hidden");    
                            }

                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            "className":      "details-control",
                            "orderable":      false,
                            "data":           null,
                            "defaultContent": '<button class="btn btn-md btn-round btn-outline-secondary btn-just-icon more-info-expand"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>'
                        },
                        {data: "user_id", searchable: false},
                        {data: "name"},
                        {data: "birth", 
                            "render": 
                                function(data, type, row) { 
                                    return getAge(row.birth);
                                }
                        },
                        {data: "mode"},
                        {data: "gender"},
                        {data: "mail"},
                        {data: "country_title"},
                        {"type": "date", data: "last_visit", searchable: false},
                        {"type": "html", data: null , "render": function(data, type, row) {return '<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-outline-secondary btn-round btn-just-icon rlogin"><i class="fas fa-chess-knight"></i></button>'} }
                    ]
                });
                // Edit record
                $("#datatable_div").on("click", ".edit", function() {
                     var rowData = datatable.row( $(this).parents('tr')).data();
                });
                //More details record

                // Add event listener for opening and closing details
               /**/ 
               $("#datatable_list tbody").on("click", "td.details-control", function () {
                    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var row = datatable.row( tr );
                    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                        // This row is already open - close it
                        row.child.hide();
                        tr.removeClass("shown");
                        $(this).html('<button class="btn btn-md btn-round btn-outline-secondary btn-just-icon"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>');
                    }
                    else {
                        getUserProfile(row.data().user_id);
                        $(this).html('<button class="btn btn-md btn-round btn-outline-secondary btn-just-icon"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>');
                        // Open this row
                        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                        tr.addClass("shown");
                    }
                } );

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I think you should make an example to reproduce this. Use jsbin or any available options.

Comment: If you try without _responsive: true_, is the problem still there? Thinking that since you havn't configured any column priority or other responsive options, this might mess with the table structure.

Comment: I have no clue what am I looking at in your third image. What is the expected result vs actual?

Comment: @Alexander Sorry for the confusion, the expected result is it will open as of desktop (second image), however in the mobile version it just doesn't do anything, nor any error message also.

Comment: @Mackan yo, you are a gun, removing responsive actually solve the expand problem, however still the row goes over page width, any idea on how to make this responsive without making it responsive :)

Comment: @mahen3d I'm not sure, but I suspect that you were not using that much from the "responsive extension". Perhaps adding a few responsive classes manually, like `width: 100%` to the table, would suffice. Or you could actually use the options provided for the "responsive extension" to set priorities on the columns (what to hide and what to show, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post this as answer since I managed to make an *informed guess* on the problem ;-)

I believed it was the "responsive" extension that was causing issues, restructuring the table and/or classes. This proved to be true.

I see two solutions:

- Remove the `responsive: true` and add some responsive classes manually to the table
- Use the options provided by the extension to prioritize how the restructuring will  be made. More on that [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/).